# Oracle Forms 6i crashes with 0xC0000005 at start after installing patch 19

Tags: oracle, patch, oracleforms

**UPD.** 0xC0000005 is `STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION`, defined in winnt.h. Meaning the app has tried to access a memory it doesn't have access to. Most of the time it's dereferencing a null pointer.

---

**In short.**
 After patch 19 has been installed I can't run any form: compiled with patch 18 or 19, by myself or others. Immediately after starting I get Windows error:

```
--------------------------------
ifrun60.exe ....
--------------------------------
The application failed to initialize properly (0xC0000005). .....
--------------------------------
```

**Details**

- In Windows Event Viewer: error id = "26", Source = "Application Popup", User = "n/a"
- I'm able to run forms from within Builder (i.e. "Program" --> "Run")
- Everything was good with Developer 6i patch 18.
- Another one programmer on our team has the same problem (others have not tried yet)
- Windows XP SP3 (32-bit).

**What I've tried**

- Add ifrun60.exe (and other exe from BIN folder) to Data execution prevention (DEP) exceptions
- Uninstall every possible component via Oracle Installer, erase ORACLE_HOME from HDD and re-install, then
- Incrementally apply all patches I have (5, 13, 15, 18, 19)
- Start form in Windows compatibility modes

**Why do I need this**
The main reason is that this patch fixes some weird behaviour that presents only on my machine (in team of 7) - I'm getting error while trying to assign global variable. It always disappears after re-compilation on any other machine and sometimes (what the... ?!) after my own recompilation later

And the second reason is, well, just curiosity because I've almost broken my brain trying to make this work

---

**Progress**
**2010.02.11** - I've just found out (thanks to ProcMon), that the last action before crush is loading *ifrcm60.dll* (with SUCCESS result code).
I've tried to replace this DLL with version from patch 18 and then *ifrun60.exe* complains about wrong DLL

**2010.02.16** - *Dr Watson* doesn't generate any info

**2010.03.02** - Support (including extended) for Designer 6i came to end on 31 dec 2008, so I can't rise support request.
Also the only mention of this problem I was able to find is the [dead thread](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=4091136) (2 y.o.) on Oracle forums

It seems to me, that the only way to solve this will be to defenestrate my PC... any other suggestions ? :)

---

**Solution**
OK, I give up. Just reinstall Windows (love this solution in any situation :) (I've done Win7 32 bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are installing patches then presumably you have an Oracle Support account.  If so, I urge you to raise an SR with them.  Or - as I'm not sure that Forms 6i is still supported -  search the Metalink Knowledge Base for solutions.

Because this is going to be something really obscure in your set-up.  There is a thread in the Tech Guy forum which covers the sort of techniques you need to deploy in diagnosing this.  [Find out more.](http://forums.techguy.org/windows-xp/665322-solved-application-failed-initialize-properly.html)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for response. I'll try Metalink once more in the nearest future. About TechGuy - I've already tried those and some other things related to the exception code.  
Funny, there even is dedicated site for it www.0xC0000005.com :). It turns out to be pretty common error that could be caused by a number of reasons

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it applying patch 6857221 for Forms 6i. You can download it here: https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/PatchSearchResults?_afrLoop=384799287815717&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=5a8q1h6fh_4 (you will need an Oracle support account)

Comment: This question is 7 years old.  Is applying this patch still relevant?  If so, could you provide a link to the patch?

Comment: Though I'm, thanks God :), no longer developing for Oracle Forms. This could be immensely useful for those who does. Could you provide more details ? Is the patch for Forms or maybe for Oracle client ? Also you seem to provide some internal number of the patch (6857221) is there more user-friendly name for this (like patch 19, as I described in OP). A link to patch info/patch notes would be great.

Comment: @Gary99 this patch is still relevant for those who want to make forms 6i work witch oracle 11 or 12. I've edited my post and added the download link.

Comment: @AlexanderMalakhov, i've editet the post and added the download link.

Comment: I don't have an Oracle Support account anymore, but thank you anyway