# Evaluating boolean values in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, if-statement

Say I have a boolean variable `foo`.

At the moment I use `IF foo = FALSE THEN ...` to compare it it, but it seems so cumbersome. There has to be a better way!

An alternative would be to rename the variable to `not_foo` but that doesn't really make it any simpler.

Is there a way to test like `IF !foo THEN ...`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use the

```
  IF NOT foo THEN...
```

Statement. [Check out this link for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1876669/evaluation-of-pl-sql-boolean-variables-in-oracle-forms)